# How do get data from the beginning of five fiscal quarters ago

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am tasked with getting data from beginning five fiscal quarters ago until present. This was not easy for an oracle novice like myself. Our fiscal year begins 1 November so this posed another dimension. Anyway, this code seems to work just fine. Just thought I would share and who knows, maybe you will find a mistake or better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few observations.

- `ADD_MONTHS(sysdate - interval '2' year, -3)` can be simplified to `sysdate - interval '2-3' year to month`.
- `TRUNC(date)` gives a date output. So no need to use TO_DATE function on it.
- I think `ADD_MONTHS(sysdate - interval '2' year, +1)` is wrong. It should be simply `sysdate - interval '2' year`. You can check by substituting
  sysdate with a date in Decemeber, `date'2013-12-04'`.

Simplified query

```
select trunc(sysdate - interval '2-3' year to month,'Q')  as beg_qtr,
       trunc(sysdate - interval '2' year,           'Q') - 1  as end_qtr
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     select (TO_DATE(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate - interval '2' year, -3),'Q'),
     'DD-MM-YY')) AS BEG_QTR, TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate - interval '2' year, +1), 'Q')
-1 AS END_QTR from DUAL
```